# send messages from child to parent process

Tags: node.js, child-process

I need to know how can i comunicate from a child process to it's parent.
I have tried this:

In my main app:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn
var cp = spawn('path/to/my/process', params)
cp.on('ready', function(){
  console.log('process is ready')
})
```

In my child process app:

```
process.emit('ready')
```

but the `console.log('process is ready')` is never executed

Answer (score 3):

Use [process.send()](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback) method to send messages from child to parent.

```js
// Parent process
const childProcess = require('child_process');
var process = childProcess.fork('child.js');

process.on('message', function (message) {
    console.log('Message from Child process : ' + message);
});
```

And in the child

```js
// child.js 

process.send('HELLO from child')
```

Answer (score 1):

Sending messages triggers an "message" event. So you could try:

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var n = cp.fork('path/to/my/process', params);

n.on('message', function(msg) {
  console.log('process is ready');
});
```

See https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle_callback

Comment: still doesn't trigger it

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez `child_process` isn't supposed to be used directly. So `var spawn = require('child_process').spawn` would be the correct syntax. Looking at your code I presume it might be `require('child_process').fork` you really want to use.

Comment: i am using spawn (see latest edit). I'm going to check out fork